# AWS Glue: attaching a VPC to access S3 using VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

AWS Glue is serverless but there is a way to assign a VPC and subnet to a Glue ETL job when the job is working with a DB connection (RDS, JDBC or RedShift). This part is fine.

The problem we are facing is when the Glue job only operated on S3 buckets and does not use any other DB.
How to make sure that Glue accesses these S3 buckets through VPC endpoint?
Even if we define a VPC endpoint for a VPC, how to ensure the ETL job runs in the same VPC?
When Glue job works on S3 source and S3 destination, it does not ask for VPC details.

Can any of you help resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make sure the traffic is not leaving VPC when the source and destination is s3. Please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) to configure s3 VPC endpoint and adding it to your Glue job.

Also refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-troubleshooting-errors.html#error-s3-timeout) if you see any issues in accessing s3.